# Entity.GetOriginal() doesn't work on some property in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

A property in the original entity has current value not original value. Other properties in the original entity have original values. The entity and the property are generated by WCF Ria services. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to server-side, than be aware that only some properties are round-tripped to the server, specificallu only propertyes marked with Key, RoundTripOriginal, ConcurrencyCheck and Timestamp. Have a look at this document: http://blogs.infosupport.com/a-guide-through-wcf-ria-services-attributes/